# Max torque given in engine specification is indicated torque or brake torque?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, torque

I want to calculate brake torque from indicated torque for motorcycle.

Comment: What is preventing you from calculating brake torque?

Comment: I've never heard the term "brake torque."  Brake horsepower comes from the use of a brake to measure torque.

Comment: Usually "torque at the engine output shaft" - especially since, unlike power, the torque varies widely depening on gearing in the gearbox, chain / drive shaft and rear wheel size.

Answer (score 0):

Brake torque usually means torque at the engine crankshaft, while there is no loss of power or toque due to transmission, powertrain or in your case the chain and gearbox.

You would have to subtract those losses if the indicated torque is the wheel torque.

Comment: Add to compensate for the extra losses...